# C# don't override overridden method

Tags: c#

is there an `attribute` or `pattern` to tell the compiler don't allow override overridable method?

For example:

**`Vehicle`**

```
public class Vehicle
{
    public virtual void Start() { }
}
```

**`Car`**

```
public class Car : Vehicle
{
    // ################
    [DontAllowOverrideAgain] //I need something like this attribute
    // ################
    public override void Start()
    {
        // Todo => codes that every car must invoke before start ...
        CarStart();
        // Todo => codes that every car must invoke after start ...
    }

    public virtual void CarStart() { }
}
```

**`CoupeCar`**

```
public class CoupeCar : Car
{
    // throw and error or show a message to developer
    public override void Start() { }

    public override void CarStart() { }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just create the first override as `sealed`, which would lead to a compile time failure that the developer can see

```
public class Car : Vehicle
{
    public sealed override void Start()
    {
        // Todo => codes that every car must invoke before start ...
        CarStart();
        // Todo => codes that every car must invoke after start ...
    }

    public virtual void CarStart() { }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i never know `sealed` work on methods too.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have it, use sealed

Ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed

```
public class Car : Vehicle
{
     sealed protected override void Start()
    {
        // Todo => codes that every car must invoke before start ...
        CarStart();
        // Todo => codes that every car must invoke after start ...
    }

    public virtual void CarStart() { }
}
```